# JBoss 7 jndi names of ejb's package in war

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, jndi

Does anyone know how to modify the "module" component of the global jndi names for ejb's deployed in a war under JBoss 7.2 (EAP 6.1)?

Per spec, the module name is the same as the base war name, which in my case includes a version number.

Here is the spec from oracle:

```
java:global/[<application-name>]/<module-name>/<bean-name>
```

In my case it yeilds:

```
java:/global/mywar-1.0/MyService
```

What I would like is:

```
java:/global/mywar/MyService
```

I know I can modify the name of the war prior to deployment, but would prefer to explicitly name the module via configuration file.  I have attempted to use the ejb-jar.xml module-name, but it had no effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved: I ended up having to include/update the xsd/namespace for the later 3.0 spec for web.xml.  This allows for a "module-name" element to be specified in the web.xml which will be used when creating the jndi name.  Tested and working on JBoss EAP 6.1.

Here's the web.xml header and module-name element:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

     <module-name>mywar</module-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create a jboss-web.xml and put it in META-INF right next to the web.xml.  Put this inside it:

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>mywar</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Cheers!

If this was packaged in an EAR, you would use the application.xml to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I actually have the context-root set up already and it is working as expected (sets the context root of the app url).  It was the jndi names assigned to the ejb's packaged in the war that I was trying to adjust.  When I set the context-root, the jndi names still contained the base war name (version included).

Comment: Gotcha - sorry I couldn't help more.