# Getting EJB module name dynamically for JNDI on EAP 7

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-7

How can we get the EJB module name dynamically for JNDI on EAP 7
we have looked into the post on stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431357/how-can-i-config-module-and-application-name-for-jndi-lookups) to get the module name

- We don't want to override in ejb-jar.xml.
- We don't want to customise    the module name in maven so it is
  fixed.
- Nor we looking are looping    at looping as we are currently
  implemented

---

```
URL url = clazz.getResource(""); 
   String [] strArray = url.getPath().split("/");  
   for (int i=0; i<strArray.length; i++){  
        if (strArray[i].contains(".jar")){  
              moduleName = strArray[i].substring(0, strArray[i].length() - 4);  
              break;  
        }  
}

jndiName = "java:app/"+moduleName+"/"+clazz.getSimpleName()+"!"+clazz.getCanonicalName();
```

Is there a cleaner way

```
java:app/<module-name>/<bean-name>!<fully-qualified-bean-interface-name>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding EJB module name by using

ejb-jar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <module-name>my-module</module-name>
</ejb-jar>
```

For application name overriding use application name in application.xml

The above solution helps in making application versioning information separate from its dependency for example while creating JNDI name to look up remote EJB in EAP 7.

Comment: For war archives you can add a entry `<module-name>` to the `web.xml`... See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416427/jboss-7-jndi-names-of-ejbs-package-in-war